# How to optimize/make faster iterating Dataframe and matching/getting data from another Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that works, but I've been looking for ways to optimize the functionality and make it faster. When I run this code it could take up to 2 hours to finish on my computer. I'm working with two Dataframes: a big DF with over 1 million rows of car parts with SKU numbers, prices, etc; and as you can see in the code example, I'm reading from a CSV sheet that has over 300k rows.

This is my code:

```
npw_inventory = pd.read_csv('inventory/npw.csv', low_memory=False)
count = 0

for _, row in pw.iterrows():
        if row['CS-SKU-NP'][5:] in npw_inventory['SKU'].values:
                matched_npw = npw_inventory.loc[npw_inventory['SKU'] == row['CS-SKU-NP'][5:]]
                min_qty = matched_npw['Min_order_Qty']
                core = matched_npw['Core_cost']
                row['MinPrice'] = (row['MinPrice'] + core) * min_qty
                count += 1 
print(count)
```

What I'm trying to answer is: 1) Is this the most efficient way to do this?, and 2) How can can I cut down the time it takes to run this code?

Data:

`pw`

> {'WD': 'A', 'LC': 'WGL', 'MasterLC': 307.0, 'Part Number': 'H6545BL',
> 'MasterSKU': '307|H6545BL', 'Weight': 2.0, 'DimWeight': 2.0,
> 'ShipWeight': 2.0, 'Length': 7.0, 'Width': 5.0, 'Height': 5.0,
> 'Total': 27.0, 'DIM': 175.0, 'UPC': '042723936655', 'Qty': 0,
> 'CS-SKU': 'AWGL|H6545BL', 'CS-SKU-NP': 'AWGL|H6545BL', 'MinPrice':
> 11.53, 'Shipping': nan, 'Carrier': nan, 'Service': nan, 'Markup': nan, 'ShipMkup': nan, 'ListMkup': nan, 'PackQty': 1.0, 'MinQty': nan,
> 'MaxQty': nan, 'Zip Code': 90746.0, 'CatSKU': nan, 'OP-Lowest(Y)':
> nan, 'VND-Lowest(Y)': nan, 'MinMkDown': nan, 'MaxMkUp': nan,
> 'Interval': nan, 'BundleSKU': nan, 'Duplicate': nan}

npw.csv

> {'Line_code': '3MM', 'SKU': '00379', 'SKU_noDS': '00379', 'Stock_1':
> 0, 'Stock_11': 0, 'Stock_12': 0, 'Stock_13': 0, 'Stock_15': 25,
> 'Stock_16': 0, 'Stock_18': 0, 'Stock_19': 0, 'Stock_2': 0, 'Stock_3':
> 0, 'Stock_4': 0, 'Stock_7': 0, 'Stock_89': 0, 'Stock_9': 0,
> 'Stock_VIC-94': 0, 'Cost': 90.36, 'Core_cost': 0.0, 'Min_order_Qty':
> 1}

Basically what's happening is I'm running a script that's a Jupyter notebook. It loads the `pw` file and does various changes with pricing and shipping. For this specific part, I match SKUs in `pw` with SKUs in `npw_inventory` to get the `Core_cost` and `Min_order_Qty`. In `pw` I add `core` to the `MinPrice` of that SKU that was matched and multiply it by the `min_qty`.

Comment: Given you're looping through rows, I imagine there's a *much* quicker way to do this. you'd be better off giving a simple example of the data in each of the files and the output you're expecting and we'll give you the quickest way to do it

Comment: Sure thing, coming up.

Comment: ... simple example of the data ideally defined as `pd.DataFrame({'CS-SKU-NP': [...], ...})`

Comment: `pw['CS-SKU-NP'].str[5:].isin(npw_inventory('SKU')` will be a much better way to check for existence **each and every rows at once**.

Comment: @QuangHoang Mind explaining how your suggestion could apply to my functionality?